# View Compound Index (.cdx) from .DBF

Tags: perl, foxpro, xbase

I am trying to write a custom FoxPro XBase database driver for Unix via Perl. I am currently able to  perform CRUD on my .dbf and .cdx indices. The point of sale software my store uses has a FoxPro based file system. The master plan behind the idea is to have a proxy between the POS and my Magento web store. Allowing real time updates between the brick and mortar store and the ecommerce solution.

My question is fairly simple and straight forward. Whats the best way to dump my .cdx file contents so i can quickly look at the indices on the .dbf file. I am currently using XBases indexdump, but this is a slow and tedious process. The dump can be platform independent and can be purchasable software if needed. I am trying to accomplish this picture from MSDN

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8tb8f47%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) from MSDN might help - it's not really a documented or discussed thing though, as someone is doing what you're doing there is no need to ever delve into the CDX structure.

Comment: As far as i have found because we are on a unix box inserting into the dbf directly via XBase and not through ODBC. If you were to go through the ODBC connection it handles indexing everything for you.

Comment: Also - Visual FoxPro is not just DBF/CDX/FPT files, there's also a database container which can have stored procedures and triggers and the like.